# Ionic 4: Overrule slide to open menu on ion- elements

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, menu, ionic4, swipe

My menu is slide-enabled so that you can swipe from left to right to open the menu.

However when I try to slide on an ion-card item (even though no slide events are active) the menu doesnt open.

I also have an ion-list with ion-item-sliding items. I only have a right to left swipe menu, so I want the left to right swipe to open the menu instead of activating a slide gesture on the item that has no effect.

Can I overrule the swipe-gestures to open the menu?

Comment: Not very sure i got your point but menu swiping by default will work even if you swipe it on a clickable button so for sure it will work on cards or whatever. Implement your menu html and the other page html since nothing is known till now and your question lacks much clarity

Comment: can you share working code example?